# changing format of variable of double type to include comma

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there a way to convert a variable of double format to add commas in between. i.e. 123456.78 should be displayed as 123,456 (I also want to get rid of the decimal).

Note: I cannot do the formatting in the VF page code because I am transposing this data to display in horizontal table instead of standard vertical data table.

Following is my controller:

```
public List<RevMonths> getRevMonths()
{
 List<RevMonths> accs = new List<RevMonths>();     
        Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;     
for (User_Stats__c a : [Select MONTH__c, Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c From User_Stats__c where Year__c = '2013' and Sales_Rep__c =: OSR and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist order by Month__c limit 10])
{
    RevMonths opp = new RevMonths((String)a.get('Month__c'),
                                              (Double)a.get('Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c'),
                                              (Double)a.get('Rental_Revenue_Goal__c'));    
    accs.add(opp);
}

 accs.sort();
 return accs;

}

public class RevMonths implements Comparable

{
public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
    return month-((RevMonths)o).month;
}

public Integer month { get; set; }
public Double Revenue { get; set; }
public Double Goal { get; set; }

public RevMonths(String mon, Double Reve, Double Gol)
{
    month = integer.valueof(mon);
    Revenue = Reve;
    Goal = Gol;
    System.debug('#### Revenue: ' + Revenue.intValue().format());
    System.debug('#### Goal: ' + Goal.intValue().format());
}
}
```

Here I want Revenue and Goals to be show with comma added to them.

Comment: What difference does a "horizontal table" vs a "vertical table" make?  Is your view still written in Visualforce?  If so, you can still use apex:outputText and format it.  Examples are here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`intValue()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Double_instance_methods.htm) and [`format()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Double_instance_methods.htm) methods of the Double class:

```
Double d = 123456.78;
System.debug('#### d: ' + d.intValue().format());

DEBUG|#### d: 123,456 <-------------------------
```

Note that:

> **format()** returns the **String value** for this Double using the **locale of the context user**

Comment: Format, of course, returns a string. So they'd have to alter their data types a little bit.

Comment: See the edited code. I have added the debug statement but the VF page still returns the double format..

Comment: @Robin You need to use a String variable for the output on the visualforce page. Like `String formatted = d.intValue().format();` And on the page like  `{!formatted}`